# Using fsolve with complex roots

Tags: matlab

I am trying to get the complex roots of the following equation

$\int_{x}^\infty Ai(\eta) d\eta=0$

Since fsolve only works with real roots, I tried to input the real and imaginary parts in a single vector as follows

```
x0=[-4,-1];
f = @(x) integral(@(n) airy(n), x, inf);
fsolve(f, x0)
```

for the root -4-i, for instance. I get this error

```
Error using integral (line 85)
A and B must be floating-point scalars.
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Any idea?

Comment: What is `cfsolve`? Is there a reason you're not using `fzero`? And "it doesn't seem to work" isn't helpful. Be specific and list any error messages in full.

Comment: I edited the post, thx for the feedback!

Comment: I honestly do not know how to calculate complex roots in MATLAB. But `fsolve` or `fzero` is to calculate only real roots as I know. I am watching your question as well for possible answers. In mathematica `FindRoot[Integrate[AiryAi[n], {n, x, Infinity}],{x,-4-I}]` gives an output like `{x -> -4.107 -1.14416i}` when you put -4-i as initial point. I hope you will find a solution. Regards!